# Bitcoin -qt or Bitcoind - which one to use for building a trading website?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, wallet

I'm building a Bitcoin website that will be fully based on wallet services and also trading. I learnt through my searching in the web that Bitcoin qt is the friendly UI version of the software while Bitcoind is just the headless daemon, but same core functionalities.

Now I was given a project to build a website that provide wallets and exchange service for users and also with trading application. Which of this two software will be the best to download? The website will be on VPS account with Godaddy.

Thanks to Nate and Pieter for warning on the security. I understand the risk but I will still love to have answer to that question.

Comment: "i was given a project to build a website that provide wallets and exchange service for users and also with trading application."  I don't mean to be rude, but I really don't think this is an appropriate project for non-experts. Bitcoin security is hard to get right, especially when involving automated transactions as a trading service necessarily will.  If you're starting from scratch, as this question suggests, I would be very uncomfortable recommending your project to customers or investors - I think it's very likely that money will be stolen.

Comment: I agree with @NateEldredge.  If you don't understand which application in Bitcoin Core you need in order to build a website, you are not ready to start building a website that uses Bitcoin.  I'd even feel a little guilty answering your question, since I feel I'd be helping to lose your customer's money.

Comment: Also, if your services run on GoDaddy, I'd like to discourage any customer from trusting you with their money.

Answer (score 1):

You should use bitcoind. You can make JSON RPC calls to it to generate an address, or to find out what the balance of an account is. Using that, you could build an application that allows access to a song if a customer pays for the song, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you Nick ODell for that information.please does it means that there is no such RPC call for bitcoin-qt ? i mean that allows access to songs if paid for.

Comment: Bitcoin-qt is a graphical application that doesn't have any RPC functionality, unless you set server=1 in Bitcoin.conf